# How to set the option type area in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, option

In Magento 1

```
($optionType == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_AREA):
```

But, in Magento 2, I have to pass responsible class object type in constructor.

How I change this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the constant variable directly:

```
($optionType == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_AREA)
```